# Solve $(1+y^2\sin2x) \;dx - 2y\cos^2x \;dy = 0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Solve $$(1+y^2\sin2x) \;dx - 2y\cos^2x \;dy = 0$$

Well, first of all I've written $M = 1+y^2\sin2x$ , $N = 2y\cos^2x$.

Then, I noticed that $M'_y$ **does not** equal to $N'_x$.

I'm trying to find something to multiply the equation with, but my math skills sucks. So I'm going for $\frac{M'_y - N'_x}{N} = h(x)$ now I need to find $h(x)$ which I'm kinda struggling to find, would love your help.

**Edit: I just noticed that $M'_y = N'_x$**

Comment: Do you know how to solve Bernoulli's equation?

Comment: @GuachoPerez Yes, you think Bernoulli will be much easier here?

Comment: Very good that you noticed! cheers!

Comment: Yes, because Bernoulli is a massaged form of a linear equation which can be solved very easily. To get a Bernoulli out of this, add the $dy$ term to both sides and divide by $2y\cos (x)^2$ and then by $dx$. You should get $y'=\sec(x)^2(2y)^{-1} +\tan(x) y$ (remember to break up the $\sin(2x)$ into $2\sin(x) \cos(x)$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the equation is exact, as

$$2y \sin 2x = 4y\cos x\sin x$$

Comment: Nope, it is exactly $2ysinx2x = 2ysin2x$

Comment: What else have I written? :)

Comment: Ilan: $ (\sin{2x}) = (2\cos x \sin x).$

Comment: @amWhy thats what I wrote right?

Comment: Yes indeed, Max...I meant to address the OP! sorry for the confusion

Comment: @amWhy sorry and thanks for clearing confusions!

Answer (score 2):

HINT:

$$y^2\sin2x\ dx-2y\cos^2x\ dy=y^2d(-\cos^2x)+d(y^2)(-\cos^2x)=d(-\cos^2x\cdot y^2)$$